# Bug :- Scanner class asks for input infinite times

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner, infinite

```
import java.util.*;
public class Composite_Magic
{
    public static void main()
    {
        int i,j,m,n,fact=0,sum=0,temp=0;
        boolean k=false;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 2 numbers as upper and lower bound and all composite numbers between them will be displayed");
        m=sc.nextInt();
        n=sc.nextInt();
        sc.close();
        if(m<n){
            for(i=m;i<=n;i++)
            {
                for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
                {
                    if(i%j==0)
                        fact++;
                }                    
                sum=i;
                while(k==false)
                {
                    temp=sum;
                    while(temp>0)
                    {
                        sum=sum+(temp%10);
                        temp=temp/10;
                    }
                    if(sum/10==0)
                        k=true;
                }
                if(sum==1 && fact>2) 
                    System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
    }
}
```

So I have asked for input only twice but it doesn't stop.

Is this a bug or some error that I'm making?

This is my complete program.

[This is the screenshot of the terminal window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QVpP.png)

Comment: can you share remaining code ?

Comment: What's the input you're typing in the console

Comment: Where is your `main()` method called ?

Comment: It will ask for input as long as you dont close the scanner.

Comment: I am not calling my main() method anywhere else in the program. I'm running it  by using void main() in the class options.

Comment: The scanner closes automatically right?

Comment: No it does not, look at my answer.

Comment: Do you want me to share the complete program? It's lengthy and might not run as the logic might be wrong.

Comment: So how do I close it? Normally the scanner asks for input and the program proceeds further.

Comment: Look at my answer. I have provided the code to close it.

Comment: @AdityaSoni the image show only 1 prompt

Comment: It prompts infinite times. The System.out.println() statement is shown only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just that this loop:

```
        while(k==false)
        {
            temp=sum;
            while(temp>0)
            {
                sum=sum+(temp%10);
                temp=temp/10;
            }
            if(sum/10==0)
                k=true;
        }
```

seems to never end.  
I don't know what you're trying to do with it, but `k` does not become `true`  
or it will take a lot of time.  
During this time you think that you're prompted to give new numbers but **you're not**.

 You're just typing and pressing enter.  
To prove this just type `ppp`. This should throw `InputMismatchException` but it does not.

Comment: I just figured out that the problem is with this loop. That loop is used to check if a number is a magic number or not. Can you help me with the logic?

Comment: I have identified the mistake and now I need help fixing it.

Comment: @AdityaSoni this is another issue. The issue of this question is solved. Now you should post another question with another title and with all the relevant info about what you're trying to achieve and where the error is

Comment: Should I delete the question because it's useless? It already has -2 thanks to my stupidity.

Comment: @AdityaSoni I don't think it's useless but it's your question and you can do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to close the scanner by using `sc.close();`
but still there is an issue with your loop I have re-implanted the code using my own code this should work now.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 2 numbers as upper and lower bound and all composite numbers between them will be displayed");
    int m = sc.nextInt();
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    sc.close();
    if (m < n) {
        for (int i = m; i <= n; i++) {
            int f = 0;
            for (int i2 = 1; i2 <= n; i2++) {
                if (n % i2 == 0)
                    f++;
            }
            if (f > 2) {
                int num = i;
                do {
                    num = sumOfDigits(num);
                } while (num > 9);
                if (num == 1) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input");
    }
}

public static int sumOfDigits(int n) {
    int s = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        s += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return s;
}
```

which makes an output of

```
10
19
28
37
46
55
64
73
82
91
100
```

Comment: Can you try the input as 10 and 100 and tell me whats the output? Is it a problem with my JDK?

Comment: Your problem is with closing the Scanner not with output.

Comment: Okay looks like 10 and 100 creates an infinite loop, can you tell me what you are trying to calculate here?

Comment: So why isn't Scanner closing itself and how is it working for you? I never had to use sc.close() before in my life.

Comment: I tried with number 1 and 2. the loop is happening on your calculations.

Comment: I'm trying to find composite magic numbers between 10 and 100. A composite number has more than 2 factors and a magic number has eventual sum of digits=1. e.g:-55=5+5=10=1+0=1

Comment: I tried with 3 and 4 too and it didn't prompt again. How is the calculation affecting the Scanner?

Comment: Okay give me a moment.

Comment: Edited my answer, please run the program and see if thats what you need to do

Comment: This is only half the program. You are only checking for composite numbers here. The number displayed should be both composite and a magic number.

Comment: Edited again.. try now

Comment: Your current output is correct for the magic number only part. I completed the program. Thanks for your help buddy!